# how to define custom sorting function for specified data types when using angular material table

Tags: angular-material

I have a table with column of `LocalDate` type which comes from the package '@js-joda/core'. And the table cannot be sorted, for it would throw an exception when handling `LocalDate`. I don't find a simple way to just past a sort function to `MatTableDataSource`, so I have to make up a class which extends `MatTableDataSource` and override its field `sortData`.

```
export class LocalDateSortableDataSource<
  T,
  P extends MatTableDataSourcePaginator = MatTableDataSourcePaginator
> extends MatTableDataSource<T, P> {
  constructor(initialData: any) {
    super(initialData);
    this.sortData = (data, sort) => {
      const active = sort.active;
      const direction = sort.direction;
      if (!active || direction == '') {
        return data;
      }
      return data.sort((a, b) => {
        let valueA = this.sortingDataAccessor(a, active);
        let valueB = this.sortingDataAccessor(b, active);
        // If there are data in the column that can be converted to a number,
        // it must be ensured that the rest of the data
        // is of the same type so as not to order incorrectly.
        const valueAType = typeof valueA;
        const valueBType = typeof valueB;
        if (valueAType !== valueBType) {
          if (valueAType === 'number') {
            valueA += '';
          }
          if (valueBType === 'number') {
            valueB += '';
          }
        }
        // If both valueA and valueB exist (truthy), then compare the two. Otherwise, check if
        // one value exists while the other doesn't. In this case, existing value should come last.
        // This avoids inconsistent results when comparing values to undefined/null.
        // If neither value exists, return 0 (equal).
        let comparatorResult = 0;
        if (valueA != null && valueB != null) {
          // Check if one value is greater than the other; if equal, comparatorResult should remain 0.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          if ((valueA as any) instanceof LocalDate) {
            comparatorResult = (valueA as any as LocalDate).compareTo(
              valueB as any as LocalDate
            );
          } else if ((valueA as any) instanceof LocalDateTime) {
            comparatorResult = (valueA as any as LocalDateTime).compareTo(
              valueB as any as LocalDateTime
            );
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          } else if (valueA > valueB) {
            comparatorResult = 1;
          } else if (valueA < valueB) {
            comparatorResult = -1;
          }
        } else if (valueA != null) {
          comparatorResult = 1;
        } else if (valueB != null) {
          comparatorResult = -1;
        }
        return comparatorResult * (direction == 'asc' ? 1 : -1);
      });
    };
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I found this question is not fixed and I have to override the field `sortingDataAccessor`. But the signature of `sortingDataAccessor` `sortingDataAccessor: (data: T, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number;` restricts me. It does't allow to return `LocalDate`.  How should I do to support sorting `LocalDate`?

Comment: Could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `sortData`, you should override the `sortingDataAccessor` and transform your property to a sortable string or number.

For any implementation of Date object it should be either number (e.g. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) or a string format in which [lexographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) should correspond to the chronological order (e.g. [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

So, for example:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MyType>(someData);
// Override the data accessor used inside `sortData`.

this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  const value = data[property];
  // Do your type check and implement logic, this is just a gist since I don't know js-joda.
  if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
    return value.toEpoch();
    // or value.toStringFormat("ISO-8601").
  }

  return value;
}
```